# Issue committing back to Azure DevOps via Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, salesforce, pipeline

I am working on a Azure Devops (ADO) pipeline which executes the following:

- Install Salesforce DX CLI
- Authenticate to an Org
- List changes in the org
- Retrieve changes in the org
- Commit the changes back to a branch in Repo (Daily_Backup)

I have both ends of the pipeline working but when I combine them into a single Job, it errors out.

```
parameters:
- name: instance
  displayName: Which Instance?
  values:
  - DEV1
  - DEV2
  - DEV3


# specific branch build
trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest
  
stages:
  - stage: DailyBackup
    displayName: Daily Backup

    variables: 
      - group: 'DevHub' # variable group
      - group: '${{ parameters.instance }}' # variable group
    
    jobs:
    - job: Execute_Daily_Snapshot
      displayName: Execute Daily Snapshot
      steps:
        - task: UseNode@0
          inputs:
           versionSpec: '16.x'
        - bash: 
            npm i sfdx-cli -g
          displayName: Install Salesforce CLI
        - bash: 
            sfdx force:auth:jwt:grant -i $(salesforceDevOrgClientId) --jwtkeyfile ./buildfiles/server.key -u $(salesforceDevOrgUserName) -r $(salesforceDevOrgInstanceURL) -a Org -s
          displayName: Authorize Salesforce Org
        - bash: 
            sfdx force:source:status -u Org
          displayName: List Changes In Instance
        - bash: 
            sfdx force:source:pull -u Org
          displayName: Retrieve Changes In Instance
        - checkout: self
          persistCredentials: true
        - script: |
            git config --global user.email pipeline@demo.com & git config --global user.name "Pipeline"
          workingDirectory: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)
        - script: |
            git checkout -b master
            echo 'This is a test' > data.txt
            git add -A
            git commit -m "deployment $(Build.BuildNumber)"
            git push --set-upstream origin master 
          displayName: Add data.txt file
          workingDirectory: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)
```

When I run just the Checkout - Commit portion, it works but when I run it at the end of this sequence, I get the following errors:

```
fatal: invalid reference: HEAD:master
[detached HEAD fad3662] A really long comment that should not get cutoff. I know I should not exceed 50 chars but I did when I started this sentence :) Solution source updated by 20230124.33 [skip ci]
 4 files changed, 1164 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 force-app/main/default/layouts/Account-Account Layout.layout-meta.xml
 create mode 100644 force-app/main/default/objects/Account/fields/Test_Field__c.field-meta.xml
 create mode 100644 force-app/main/default/profiles/Admin.profile-meta.xml
 create mode 100644 force-app/main/default/profiles/Read Only.profile-meta.xml
push code to repo
fatal: could not read Password for 'https://{orgID}@dev.azure.com': terminal prompts disabled
##[error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.
```

I have tried reorganizing the flow of which elements fall in which order to no avail. I am not sure what else to try since I know the individual components work on their own.

I am wondering if it's something related to the switch from Node.js Bash to Script formatting but cannot seem to find any answers here.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

I was trying to checkout the `Master` branch again in my commit action but when I run a `git switch -c DailyBackup` it works fine.